# Cannot execute "pwd" in remote shell in Docker

Tags: neo4j

I'm running a neo4j server on AWS in Docker

The docker container running neo4j is sharing the network interface with the host, eg I start it with "--net=host"

in neo4j.properties I have

```
..    
remote_shell_host=0.0.0.0
remote_shell_enabled=true
remote_shell_port=1337
```

In neo4j-wrapper I have the following parameters

```
   ..
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=debian
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
   wrapper.java.additional=-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

When connecting to the shell from another machine, I get

```
root@5a9ad402ae02:/var/lib/neo4j/bin# ./neo4j-shell -host xx.xx.xxx.xx
Welcome to the Neo4j Shell! Enter 'help' for a list of commands
NOTE: Remote Neo4j graph database service 'shell' at port 1337

neo4j-sh (?)$ pwd
Exception creating connection to: 172.17.0.5; nested exception is:
    java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
neo4j-sh (?)$ help
Exception creating connection to: 172.17.0.5; nested exception is:
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

The strange thing is that the shell tries to connect to 172.17.0.5. This ip is the adress of the local host that I use to connect to the remote shell from. Why is the shell trying to go back to my local host?

Comment: there are many weird things with remote RMI :( it uses random port ranges, which you probably have to expose as well.

Comment: you might be better of running `docker exec` inside of that container for the shell

Comment: I'm aware of the weird things with RMI, I have exposed all ports on the server and I tried to lock the ports down with  wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
   wrapper.java.additional=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099

Comment: Also the error is strange. It looks like the neo4j server is trying to open a connection at the client. This adress, 172.17.0.5 is the ip of my local machine. Why can I start the shell without errors, but no run a command